# Vaadin Grid disable editor when editor is active

Tags: grid, editor, vaadin, vaadin7

I am using Vaadin 7.4 and I try to handle the situation, when a user want to close the editor when editing a row.
While trying this, the method setEditorEnabled(false) throws an IllegalstateException. I did not want to handle this Exception, so I check, if isEditorActive(). When it is active, I cancel the editor.

```
    if(getGrid().isEditorActive())
    {
        getGrid().cancelEditor();
    }

    getGrid().setEditorEnabled(editMode);
    setEditButtonDescription(editMode);

    getAppendButton().setVisible(editMode);
    getDeleteButton().setVisible(editMode);
    getResetButton().setVisible(editMode);
    getSaveButton().setVisible(editMode);
```

My problem is, that after the cancelEditor() call, the setEditorEnabled(false) is not working. The grid is still editable.

When I does not call the cancelEditor() method, the setEditorEnabled(false) is working.

Does anyone know, where I made a mistake?
Maybe there is another solution for the problem or I just have to catch the exception.

Thanks

Comment: This is probably happening due minor issue in the framework. There are couple issue report, that may be related https://github.com/vaadin/framework/issues/10688 and https://github.com/vaadin/framework/issues/10413 . In your case catching that exception is one approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is fixed in Vaadin 8.5.1.

Comment: Thanks for the message!